# Iterate over props.children

Tags: react-native

In this case `item.Definition` is always a js array.
I want to map each element of `item.Definition` (used as `props.children`) to a `<Text>` element.

```
<Header title={item.title}>  {item.Definition}  </Header>
```

This is the component

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View {...this.props} >
                <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
                <View>{
                    this.props.children ? this.props.children.map( item => <Text>{item}</Text> ) : "aaaaa";
                }</View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I get the usual error: "cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode.."

Answer (score 1):

A String array or a string can never be a valid yoga node/child. A Yoga node is one that is any valid **native `widget`** being bridged to react native UI APIs.

**Coming to solution to your problem, I would approach it like the below**

If `item.Definition` is a JS array of data i assume then why don't we pass it to your `Header` as prop ?

Your code should look like this:

```
<Header title={item.title} definition ={item.Definition}/>
```

Provided your Header should be like below:

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const {definition} = this.props;
        return (
            <View {...this.props} >
                <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
                <View>
                {definition.length>0 && definition.map((item) => {
                  return (<Text>{item}</Text>) //considering item to be string.
                 })}
                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 mistakes here:

1) `<Text>{item}</Text>` must not be the type of an object. Assume if an `item` is an object, you must print an attributes contain in an object not the object itself for eg: `<Text>{item.name}</Text>`

2) `"aaaaa"` is not a single string, must be wrap in text. 
for eg: `<Text>aaaaa</Text>`

```
class Header extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View {...this.props} >
            <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
            <View>{this.props.children ?
                     this.props.children.map( item => <Text>{item}</Text> ) : 
                     <Text>aaaaa</Text>}</View>

        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that issue because you are not wrapping the static string "aaaaa" in Text component.
One other issue is you are trying to render object in text component which is also gonna throw error. So fix those and you component will work just fine.